# Oracle SQL Query to retrieve metadata

Tags: oracle11g

I need one single sql query which will retrieve me all the metadata information from a schema.We wont be able to create a database link here . So, need to dump the metadata from both the schemas in 2 different tables and then compare the schema

Comment: a) What level of depth do you need?

b) What objects do you need?

c) What have you tried?

Comment: user_objects
user_role_privs
user_sys_privs
user_tab_privs
user_tab_columns
user_indexes      
user_ind_columns  
user_constraints
user_sequences
user_synonyms
user_triggers
user_jobs
user_db_links

Comment: That's for (a) and (b). Now, once again - what have YOU tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it before for someone else. If you like it feel free to use it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_prc
AS
BEGIN
    NULL;
END;


CREATE FUNCTION copy_fun RETURN BOOLEAN
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN TRUE;
END;


CREATE PACKAGE copy_pkg AS
    PROCEDURE pkg_prc;
END copy_pkg;


CREATE PACKAGE BODY copy_pkg AS
    PROCEDURE pkg_prc
    AS
    BEGIN
        NULL;
    END;
END copy_pkg;


CREATE TABLE source_codes
(
    s_database     VARCHAR2(30)
,   s_package_name VARCHAR2(30)
,   s_source_code  CLOB
);


DECLARE
    CURSOR objects_cur IS
        SELECT  object_name, DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(object_type, object_name) r_source_code
        FROM    dba_objects
        WHERE   owner       =  USER
        AND     object_type IN ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE')
        AND     object_name IN ('COPY_PRC', 'COPY_FUN', 'COPY_PKG');

    TYPE objects_ntt IS TABLE OF objects_cur%ROWTYPE;

    l_objects  objects_ntt;
    l_database_name  VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    OPEN  objects_cur;
    FETCH objects_cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_objects;
    CLOSE objects_cur;

    l_database_name := sys_context('USERENV', 'DB_NAME');

    FORALL indx IN 1..l_objects.COUNT
        INSERT INTO source_codes
        (
            s_database
        ,   s_package_name
        ,   s_source_code
        )
        VALUES
        (
            l_database_name
        ,   l_objects(indx).object_name
        ,   l_objects(indx).r_source_code
        );

    COMMIT;
END;

SELECT  s_database, s_package_name, DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(s_source_code, 40)
FROM    source_codes;
/*
my_db_name COPY_FUN "  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SCHEMA_NAME".""
my_db_name COPY_PKG "  CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "SCHEMA_NAME"."C"
my_db_name COPY_PRC "  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA_NAME"."
*/
```

Comment: I am using Informatica to connect to different database schema , fire one query and retrieve the metadata information , dump into 2 different tables.One table will have all the meadata information about the first db schema and the other table will have all the metadata information about the second db schema.

Comment: It is schema independent: "dba_objects". In your case it may be better to use "all_objects". PowerCenter can run PL/SQL from file.